# math.exp() is returning 0 for floats

Tags: python, math, exp

I've included the relevant code for my issue. When I run the code my feet to meters function works as expected. `-M*g*z/(T*R)` inside of the math.exp() operation gives a negative float of decent size. Despite this, my function `Pressure()` returns only `0.0`, like this: `z = 1000 ft, P = 0.0 atm`. What am I doing wrong? I've made sure everything is a float so I don't get truncation, but I am still having issues. Any response would be appreciated! Thanks!

```
def Pressure(z):
    Po=1.0 #atm
    M=29.0 #kg/kmol
    g=9.81 #m/s^2
    T=300.0 #K
    R=0.082057 #Latm/molK
    return math.exp(-M*g*z/(T*R))

def ft_to_m(x):
    return float(3.28084*x)

for i in range(0,30001): #i in ft
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print("z =",i,"ft, P =",Pressure(ft_to_m(i)), "atm") 
    continue
```

Comment: `-M*g*z` is up to `-28000985`, and `T*R` is about `24.6`, the result of the division is `-1137460`, which means that you're doing `e` to the power of `-1137460`, which is incredibly close to `0`. So, unless it's a precision problem (because you expected `0.00000000...something`), I'd say this is the correct behavior.

Comment: value of -M*g*z/(T*R) is coming out to be in order of -10^5. Are you expecting this? This is the reason for Zero Value

Comment: Even with an input of `10` you just get a result of `2.1661586618229392e-165`.

Comment: BTW, the `for` loop looks strange. You don't need `continue` because the loop will continue anyway. And if you would use `for i in range(0, 30001, 1000):` you could drop the `if i % 1000 == 0:` too.

Comment: Check your units.  The argument to math.exp must be dimensionless.  Make sure that all your units cancel out and leave you with a dimensionless number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether it's your formula (`-M*g*z/(T*R)`) that's wrong or you're misunderstanding `math.exp`: `math.exp(x)` is e<sup>x</sup>.

Here your `x` (the result of your formula) is already `-37915` at the first step and it only goes downhill from there. e<sup>-38000</sup> is pretty much a complex way to write `0` since Python uses mere 64-bit floating-point integers.

edit: looks to be your formula: M = 29 *g* / kmol (or worse lb/lb-mol) not kg/kmol, you may also want to check your values for R and K.

Basically review all your values, then do a dimensional analysis to ensure the units fit together (it doesn't help that you're using non-SI units like atm so "standard" list of constants for the barometric formula don't apply as-is).

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `print(-M*g*z/(T*R))` before the *return* shows large negative exponents, giving a result so close to zero that *exp()* will underflow. (The first two exponents are -37,915 and -75,830).

This is likely more of an input data problem than an issue with your code.

Putting the same values in a pocket calculator will also give zero:

```
>>> exp(-37915)
0.0
```